# devexpress clientside event pass string

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, combobox, devexpress

I have a devexpress combobox control, on the 'valueChanged' event, I call some client-side code. Inside this code I have an `alert()` to which I'd like to pass a `c# string`.

I've seen posts on SO that say use something like `@Html.Raw(string)` however, this doesn't seem to be working with this dev-express control. My alert just keeps spitting out  anything as a string like:

`alert('@Html.Raw(someC#String)');`

comes out as: `@Html.Raw(someC#String)`

```
string text = "text message";
@Html.DevExpress().ComboBox(
  settings =>
  {
    settings.Properties.ClientSideEvents.ValueChanged = "function(s,e) 
    { alert('@text'); }";
```

the above snippet isn't displaying correctly by the way, everything inside the double quotes should show up like a string, on the `settings.Properties.ClientSideEvents.ValueChanged` line

Comment: `{ alert('@text')` looks like the quotes around the text variable is your problem..

Comment: @MethodMan I tried `alert(@text);` without single quotes, and it didn't work, it actually made the combo-box not work at all

Comment: sounds like you may need to consult with the `DevExpress` documentation in regards to how to show message dialog using java alert method..

Comment: check out their site [DevExpress Support](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Demos/)